# magento 2 : knockout value render not working under script template

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I want to render `textname` value using knockout under `<script>` template.

Here is the script

**.phtml file**

```
<div id="test_id" data-bind="scope: 'test-scope'">
    <span data-bind="text:textname"></span> <!-- successfully render textname --> 
</div>

<script id="custom-template" type="text/x-magento-template">
    <span data-bind="text:textname2"></span> // not rendered
</script>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "test-scope": {
                    "component": "Custom_Module/js/custom"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**js file**

```
define([
'jquery',
'ko'
], function($,ko) {
'use strict';
 return function(config) {
  this.textname = "this is very good name";
  this.textname2 = "this is textname 2";
 }
});
```

Is there any way to render this. Actually, I am rendering the select options using knockout. Under script template it does not render.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try with <span><%- data.textname2 %></span>

Comment: You must define the scope, for you you can write your js file

Comment: For the template you can use magetemplate

Comment: I have defined this `'mage/template',` too. but not working

Comment: @zedBlackbeard - Will you had your solution as an answer if you ever came across one?